# Creating subset by using regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having the following list of dimension-elements (not complete, in reality it's much longer):

```
Ktr_12345_180
Ktr_12345_160
Ktr_12345_1130
Kst_12345_180
Kst_12345_112
Kst_12345_120
Kst_12345_160
```

My goal is to create a subset of elements in Jedox 2019.1 Subset-Editor. 
The subset should include all elements starting with the prefix `"Ktr_"` while not having the suffix `_160` or `_180`

I already built a Regex `(Ktr_)+[0-9]+(_180|_160)` which identifies the Elements I don't want.

Now I have to invert it. From my knowledge there is no native function for inverting a regular expression, right?

So I tried to do this by using a negative lookahead: `(Ktr_)+[0-9]+(?!(_180|_160))`

This does not work at all. I tried this in various shapes, not reaching my goal...

I expect the regex to deliver the wanted elements. Instead it just shows every element having `"Ktr_"` as prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex you need is this,

```
\bKtr_[0-9]+_(?!1[68]0\b)[0-9]+\b
```

Here `\b` word boundaries around the regex ensure it doesn't give a partial match in larger text and `(?!1[68]0\b)` is the negative look ahead required for rejecting strings that are either `160` or `180` and rest of the pattern is similar to yours. Also, unless you need a group, you don't need to write first part as `(Ktr_)+` and also this will allow `Ktr_` whole of it one or more times which looking at your samples don't think you want. So I've changed it to simple `Ktr_` only but in case that was a valid one and indeed needed, retain it by replacing `Krt_` with `(Ktr_)+`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/monjhB/1)**

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `+` is greedy only as much as it serves the whole pattern to match; in `[0-9]+` it doesn't match *all* following digits, but only all *such that the rest of the pattern matches as well*.

Capture the variable part of the pattern (`[0-9]+`) and print it out to see

```
my @ary = qw(
    Ktr_12345_180
    Ktr_12345_160
    Ktr_12345_1130  
    Kst_12345_180
);

for (@ary) { 
    say "got $1  in $_"  if /(Ktr_[0-9]+)(?!_180|_160)/;
}
```

and we get

```
got Ktr_1234   in Ktr_12345_180
got Ktr_12345   in Ktr_12345_1130
got Ktr_1234   in Ktr_12345_160
```

Matching `1234` leaves `5` to satisfy the lookahead's "not _180" as the next thing after the `1234`.

To adjust this we need data details and the question appears to allow two possibilities

- If there is always a `_` following, as sample data suggests, then simply include `_` before the lookahead

  ```
  /Ktr_[0-9]+_(?!180|160)/
  ```

  what now requires all digits to be matched before `_`.  This also "enforces" the `_` there
- If we follow what the text says

  > all elements starting with the prefix "Ktr_" while not having the suffix _160 or _180

  then there may not be anything following `Ktr_12345` (for example), or at least not a `_`

  In this case only force all consecutive digits to be matched

  ```
  /Ktr_[0-9]++(?!_180|_160)/
  ```

  where the extra `+` makes its preceding subpattern match as much as it can, regardless of what follows further in the whole pattern; it goes under the name of [possesive quantifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Possessive-quantifiers)

Comment: @ikegami Ah, but of course!  Something's been nagging me ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to match the pattern and then negate against the negative lookbehind.

Try this

```
$ cat paul.txt
Ktr_12345_180
Ktr_12345_160
Ktr_12345_1130
Kst_12345_180
Kst_12345_112
Kst_12345_120
Kst_12345_160
$ perl -lne ' print if /(Ktr_).+?(?<!_180|_160)\b/ ' paul.txt
Ktr_12345_1130
$ perl -lne ' print if /(Ktr_)+[0-9]+.+?(?<!_180|_160)\b/ ' paul.txt
Ktr_12345_1130
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a possessive quantifier with an additional `+` to ensure that the `[0-9]+` matches as many digits as are present and doesn't try backtracking when the match fails.

```
(Ktr_)+[0-9]++(?!(_180|_160))
```

[Possessive quantifiers](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Possessive-quantifiers) are available since Perl 5.10, or before then with the [independent subexpression](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#%28%3F%3Epattern%29) syntax.